# Why the output are different when I use the parameter to call the function, and invoke the function by() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, return, invoke

```
 function a() {
     console.log('A!');
     function b(){
         console.log('B!'); 
     }
     return b;
 }
```

When I do like this,

```
 var s = a();
```

Here is the output:

```
 A!
```

When I do like this,

```
 a();
```

The output is as below:

```
 A!
 ƒ b(){
     console.log('B!'); 
 }
```

I wonder why there the outputs are different.

Comment: because you are doing it in the console and the last statement is outputted....

Comment: Answer updated : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49461652/1636522.

Answer (score 2):

Because the function `a` returns a function `b`.

So, doing this `console.log(a())` will print the source code of function `b`.

If you want to execute the returned function, just call it:

```js
function a() {
  console.log('A!');

  function b() {
    console.log('B!');
  }

  return b;
}

var s = a()
console.log(s);
console.log("--------------------------------------")
s();
```

Comment: Yes, I got this part. But I'm wondering why var s = a() is not returning the b object

Comment: @XinyiLi yes, it's returned by function `a`.  Because of that, you can call it as follow: `a()()`

Comment: The question is "Why `var s = a();` and `a();` have different outputs ?".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434869/why-the-output-are-different-when-i-use-the-parameter-to-call-the-function-and/49434966?noredirect=1#comment85872332_49435127

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434869/why-the-output-are-different-when-i-use-the-parameter-to-call-the-function-and/49434966?noredirect=1#comment85871669_49434869

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you're returning `b` itself instead of `b`'s result (`b()`).

And, because you've ran the function in the console, the result of `a` (that is, the function `b`) will be displayed in it's "code form".

Comment: Wrong, there is no relation with calling `b` or not.

Comment: Yes there is. The function is returing ```b``` instead of ```b```'s result. Maybe you've misundertood what I said...

Comment: The question is "Why `var s = a();` and `a();` have different outputs ?".

Comment: Oh, then that's because using `var` dosen't return the function's result.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to understand your question, but for my defense it looks that there are multiple questions into one, dusted with conflicting statements, omissions and typos ("by()" instead of "b()" ?). To put it simply, we can feel the confusion in your mind :-)

For example, you talk about parameters, but none of your functions takes parameters. Moreover, you seem to believe that you invoke `b` at some point, but there is nothing like `b();` in your code. Finally, you never tell us, but you are coding directly into the browser's console, right ?

That being said, here is how I would summarize the main question :

> Why `var s = a();` and `a();` have different outputs ?

You said that `var s = a();` prints `A!`, while `a();` prints `A!` plus function `b`. Actually, `a();` does not print function `b`, this additional output comes from the browser's console. Keep in mind that there are two types of outputs, the ones that you ask for explicitly with `console.log(...)`, and the ones produced by the console itself. As [epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello) stated, "in the console [...] the last statement is outputted". If you write `a();` into the console and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, the last statement is `a()`, and since `a` returns `b`, the console outputs function `b`. If you write `var s = a();`, `a` still returns `b` but the console doesn't tell you because `a()` is not the last statement anymore. I'm not sure but in this case I would say that `var` is the last statement, and since `var` returns nothing, the console outputs nothing.